# Heroku naked domains with DNS & SSL

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I've been struggling with the configuration of my DNS app on Heroku. Things I want to accomplish:

`www.example.com` and `example.com` , both with SSL config (HTTPS)

Things I tried so far ...

> GoDaddy Settings:
>
> CNAME | www | example.com.herokudns.com
>
> FOWARDING to
> https://www.example.com

However, this setup is working great with HTTP only, but I'm getting a "Your connection is not private" error when I type the https.

I checked several tutorials and none address this issue.

PS: I'm using the SSL automatically managed from heroku.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED IT

Getting the naked domain set up with Godaddy easily: Set forwarding to your domain: https://www.my-domain.com. This will redirect non www to the correct place.

With that, I don't actually need to add a second domain in heroku (example.com).

Just keep the www.example.com, turn the SSL on, go to go daddy and redirect. This is working for me so far....